# Android : getting result from an activity without finish call in that activity

Tags: android

In my application Activity A has a list of items
on choosing a product i go to activity B that give details of that item and a button "Choose this item"
which will go to activity C.
In actvity C this choosen item is displayed and there is a button "choose more items"
on clicking this i have to go back to activity A, and repeat the same steps.
BUt when another item is choosen, activty C should display both items.

SO i thought from actvity C, i start activity A, by calling `startActivityForResult()` and add the result to existing list of items.
In that case, i have to call `finish()` of A to retrn value.
Is this right way of implementing

Since "choose more items" can be clicked many times in real life, wont it end up killing and starting many times the same activity
I have set the launch mode as single task for the activities

What would be the best way to handle this situation

thanks a lot for your time and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I will suggest that you can take a static List or ArrayList and work accordingly.

**1.)** You can take a public static List and can initialize as per your requirement, something like this.

```
public static List<CartListClass> cartlist = new ArrayList<CartListClass>();
```

**2.)** You can access this from any class using `Acitivity_name.cartList` and add the required information.

**3.)** Now, when you will come to `Activity C` you will have all the required information in the static List, so from there you can get and show the required Details of the product.

And, the static List will maintain the information also, when you select another product or item from `Activity A to Activity C`, it will be added to the List below the previous item or product.

**UPDATE:**

Better approach would be using `BroadCastReceiver` to update the value or using `Interface`.

Comment: This is a very easy solution. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I would save identifiers of chosen items in Activity C to preference. 
So, in resume of Activity C, I'd check how many I have in the saved preference and load corresponding data to views.